# Continue training CoreML Model

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, turi-create

I'm trying to get a better understanding on how to create object detection models in Turi Create (for usage in CoreML). I'm trying to create a model that detects custom images I designed and printed myself. To avoid having to take a huge amount of photo's, I'm figured I'd use the `one-shot-object-detection` feature provided by Turi Create. So far so good. I feed the algorithm two starter images and it successfully generates the synthetic data set and creates a somewhat reliable model.

Now I'm wondering what happens when I want to add a third category. I could of course add a third starter image and run the code again, but this feels like 2/3th of the work is redundant...

Is there a way to continue training a previously trained model, or combine multiple models so I don't have to retrain my models from scratch every time I add a category? If not, any other ways to get this done (e.g. TensorFlow)?

Answer (score 1):

Turi Create is rather limited in the options it offers for retraining (none, basically). If you want more control over the process, using a tool such as TensorFlow is the better choice.